# How do I make my javascript embed code responsive?

Tags: javascript

I have an embed code from ShootProof with dimensions input that I want to make width responsive. I tried to change the width to 100% and it gives a blank page.

I'm sure this is simple, but any help is appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _spRemote={width:960,height:650};var _ce = parseInt(Math.random() * 99999999);
  document.write('<sc' + 'ript type="text/javascript" src="https://proofs.carlasphotos.com/remote/embed?ce=' + _ce + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
</script>
```

Comment: Is this script just embedding an iFrame? If so, just add `iframe { width:100%; }` to your css.

Comment: can you not just remove the hard values for with and height?

Comment: @APAD1 There is no iframe, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pete What would I put in place of the hard values?

Comment: @ihaveaquestion yes there is, that's what this script is doing, [embedding an iframe](https://i.ibb.co/0F7s1nP/Screen-Shot-2019-04-08-at-11-33-02-AM.png). All you need to do is set the CSS on that iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embed script you provided is just placing an `iframe` into the `body` of your document, you can control the width of the iframe with CSS. Because the iframe is being injected with inline styling, you will have to use `!important` to override the width:

```
iframe { width:100%!important; }
```

Comment: that did it! Thank you!